# Yii2: How to link from backend to frontend when both are in the same domain?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to try to make an `URL` from backend to frontend, I tried to add the following code in `backend/config/main.php` but it didn't worked.

```
'urlManagerFrontEnd' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
    'baseUrl' => '/',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
],
```

Then when I tried this code, it showed `"localhost/admin"` instead just `"localhost"` (where the frontend is).

```
echo Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'test'), [Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createUrl(['/'])]);
```

Just for reference, both `frontend/web` and `backend/web` are inside a folder called `"public"`. `frontend/web` is in the root of `public` folder while `backend/web` is inside an `admin` folder which is inside the `public` one.

Answer (score 0):

An example of implementation on a project with three subdomains.

Config in common

```
'urlManagerBackend' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    [
        'hostInfo' => env('BACKEND_HOST_INFO'),
        'baseUrl' => env('BACKEND_BASE_URL'),
    ],
    require(Yii::getAlias('@backend/config/_urlManager.php'))
),
'urlManagerFrontend' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    [
        'hostInfo' => env('FRONTEND_HOST_INFO'),
        'baseUrl' => env('FRONTEND_BASE_URL'),
    ],
    require(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/config/_urlManager.php'))
),
```

Env - it is configuration file

FRONTEND_HOST_INFO    = http://site.lan

BACKEND_HOST_INFO     = http://admin.site.lan

another project, realization -  backend - web.php

```
$config = [
 'components' => [
     'urlManagerF' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'baseUrl'=>env('FRONTEND_HOST_INFO'),
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [],
        ],
        'urlManagerS' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'baseUrl'=>env('STORAGE_HOST_INFO'),
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [],
        ],
    ],
],
```